# How To find Category Level ON POS Database

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am trying to find Retail Category node level at POS database, in AOS table ECORESCATEGORY has field LEVEL_ with correct values, but on POS, this field is just showing zero value for all items.

*How can i make sure that this field gets synced with AOS?*

I tried jobs N-1040 and N-1100, but this field is not updated.

Following is SQL query i use:

```
select  distinct Category, it.ItemID, MAX(IName.Name) Name, isnull(Level_,0) -1
        from    InventTable it Inner Join           
                (
                    Select Distinct PRODUCT, category, CATEGORYHIERARCHY
                    From EcoResProductCategory 
                    Where CATEGORYHIERARCHY In (select Top 1 CATEGORYHIERARCHY
                                                    from EcoResCategoryHIERARCHYRole
                                                    where NAMEDCATEGORYHIERARCHYROLE = 4 --Retail
                                                )
                ) pcat on it.PRODUCT = pcat.PRODUCT Left Join
                EcoResCategory cat on pcat.category = cat.recid Left Join
                EcoResProductTranslation IName on it.PRODUCT = iname.PRODUCT 
        group by Category, it.ItemID, isnull(Level_,0) -1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want to identify Items hierarchy on POS database, for example, if items are assigned retail category RETAIL CATEGORY > BRAND > DEPARTMENT > CATEGORY, I want to list all items which falls under head DEPARTMENT, in ECOResCategory, there is a field LEVEL_, which identify category node's Level, this field is not updated in POS database. but at AOS, I can see this field updated with values. I think they did not implement this yet.